# Why in clause to delete multiple rows not and operator

Tags: sql

I am new to sql ,I was trying to delete a two row.(sno 5 and 6)

which is shown below.

```
+----+----------+--------------+
|sno |   gender | linkin_sno   |
+----+----------+--------------+
|1   |   Male   |   1          |
|2   |   Male   |   2          |
|3   |   Female |   3          |
|4   |   Female |   4          |
|5   |   Akash  |   5          |
|6   |   Ashok  |   6          |
+----+----------+--------------+
```

I have wrongly inserted name in my gender table.so I tried to delete using query

I initially wrote a query ,which is:

```
delete from linkin_foreign where gender='Akash'and gender='Ashok';
```

And then i googled and found the Right query and it is:

```
delete from linkin_foreign where gender in ('Akash','Ashok');
```

Here comes my question,why sql accepts only "in" clause to delete two rows where as "and" operator is not allowed to delete multiple rows.Is there any specific rule in sql,share your knowledge to this fresher.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you put and in where clause, it means you want to delete a row which has both the names Akash and Ashok as gender. Which does not match with any row. You either need to use 'or' or 'in' in where clause

Answer (score 1):

SQL doesn't require `in`.  Your original query has faulty logic.  With the correct logic, it works:

```
delete from linkin_foreign
    where gender = 'Akash' or gender = 'Ashok';
```

However, `in` is the better approach:  simpler to write, less prone to error, and (in some databases) easier to optimize.

Comment: It is working perfectly with your query @GordonLinoff. and sorry for my ignorance.